# Rails list created/updated records within last 24 hours

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, list, activerecord

I'm trying to list records for a locations view of recently created at or updated records from the last 24 hours using activerecord but am a beginner developer needing some help.

Does anyone know a solution for implementing this in the controller/view? Thanks in advance for the help.

Answer (score 50, accepted):

Since you're using Rails, I will assume that you have these files, corresponding to a Locations resource:

```
app/views/locations/index.html.erb
app/controllers/locations_controller.rb
app/models/location.rb
```

There are a few ActiveRecord alternatives for querying records in the past 24 hours:

1. This example demonstrates the concept that you can specify a range for querying the timestamp columns.

   ```
   @locations = Location.where(updated_at: (Time.now - 24.hours)..Time.now)
   ```
2. As pointed out in the comments below, there may be a fraction of a second precision error with the above query.  You can store a variable, `now = Time.now`, to ensure that your query spans exactly 24 hours.

   ```
   now = Time.now
   @locations = Location.where(updated_at: (now - 24.hours)..now)
   ```
3. You could eliminate the subtraction operation and let Rails handle it for you, which may also result in a slight offset from an exact window of 24 hours.

   ```
   @locations = Location.where(updated_at: 24.hours.ago..Time.now)
   ```
4. You can also forego the hash syntax in the `where` parameters, passing a SQL string that filters with the `>` comparison operator.

   ```
   @locations = Location.where('updated_at > ?', 24.hours.ago)
   ```

In your controller, add an index action, with your preferred query approach:

```
def index
  @locations = Location.where(updated_at: 24.hours.ago..Time.now)
end
```

In your view, add these lines:

```
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Id</th>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Created_At</th>
      <th>Updated_At</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <% @locations.each do |location| %>
      <tr>
        <td><%= location.id %></td>
        <td><%= location.name %></td>
        <td><%= location.created_at %></td>
        <td><%= location.updated_at %></td>
      </tr>
    <% end %>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: why 120.day? Was the question modified?

Comment: No it was not. That was just another random example. I updated the answer to use `24.hours` for agreement with the Q. Thanks for checking!

Comment: Also works: `Location.where(updated_at: 1.day.ago..Time.now)`

Comment: Nope, sorry `1.day.ago` introduces an error which is seen in the database call: `SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE ("users"."updated_at" BETWEEN '2016-02-05 15:10:19.453553' AND '2016-02-06 15:10:19.454078')`. Note that the time is slightly different. Best is `now=Time.now; User.where(updated_at: (now - 1.day)..now)`.

Comment: @Adobe Any explanation as to why?

Comment: @pixatlazaki: because you have to keep your reference point fixed. So you put it in `now` in variable, and use `(now - 1.day)..now` range.

Comment: I adapted the first step of the answer because I needed to get a single record from 24 hours' ago. When using `Location.where(updated_at: Time.now - 24 hours)`  what happens when there (almost inevitably) isn't a record exactly 24 hours' ago? Does it take the nearest record, or the 'next' one. E.g. if I called `Location.where(updated_at: Time.now - 24 hours)` at midday today, and records existed yesterday at 11:59am and 12:03pm, which would be returned? (I think nothing will get returned unless it's *exactly* 24 hours' ago, but I could be wrong?)